# JQ: Merging different objects into a new array

Tags: json, jq

I use jq 1.5 in a Windows enviroment to modify json files. 
Hi have following json file:

```
{"player_container":{"74016":["None","None","None","None","None","None","None","None"],"74002":["None","None","None","ta81a928e0624295b01499d7035d0308","tdd4e222600d42f9954b0be0448da0b1","None","None","None"],"74007":["None","None","None","None","None","None","None","None"],"74009":["None","None","None","None","None","None","kcb810a423dd4e179027f0feaae9ea60","None"],"74012":["x720ed571876471fab173ba05f71e4b3","None","None","None","None","None","None","None"],"74013":["None","None","None","None","None","None","None","None"],"74014":["vd86094b5a6e448f8c416d6fe75bec7c","None","None","h6ef696cf767464f9c367150fdb29fe4","None","g77b124cd46b41399c3db219ac0a76bd","None","None"],"74015":["None","None","None","None","None","None","None","None"]}}
```

In the object player_container are different objects (the "name" of the object and the number objects differs from time to time).
I use following jq command actually to join them into a new array:

```
.player_container | .[] | [{ user_id: .[]}]
```

But it generates different json Arrays and not one. What i need looks like:

```
   [
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "ta81a928e0624295b01499d7035d0308"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "tdd4e222600d42f9954b0be0448da0b1"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "kcb810a423dd4e179027f0feaae9ea60"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "x720ed571876471fab173ba05f71e4b3"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "vd86094b5a6e448f8c416d6fe75bec7c"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "h6ef696cf767464f9c367150fdb29fe4"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "g77b124cd46b41399c3db219ac0a76bd"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "None"
  }
]
```

Any tips?

BR
Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to move one character:

```
[.player_container | .[] | { user_id: .[]}]
```

While your version creates a separate array for each output of `.player_container | .[]`, this will collect everything into one array.

Comment: Hi Michal, blind on both eyes. Thanks!